# Prevent turbolinks 5 to load on certain <a></a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

I have several examples of the following. 
A link like this with no real href:

```
<a href="#" id="add-item">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</a>
```

And some JS that does some magic:

```
id = $('#watch-path-group').children().length + 1
$('#watch-path-group').append '<input style="margin-top: 4px;" id=wp_"' + id + '" name=wp_"' + id + '" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="New path...">'
```

After upgrading to turbolinks 5 the behaviour has changed. When I click the link turbolinks steps in and reloads the page and in this case the newly added element disappears...

I understand that this is probably more or less what turbolinks does. Taken from [github](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks):

> Turbolinks intercepts all clicks on  links to the same domain. When you click an eligible link, Turbolinks prevents the browser from following it. Instead, Turbolinks changes the browser’s URL using the History API, requests the new page using XMLHttpRequest, and then renders the HTML response.

But how do I accomplish what I am trying to do. Should I stop using link tags as described?

Thanks

Comment: To be clear: what you're trying to do is run the 2nd piece of js code after turbolinks does its thing?

Comment: @yezzz No... Well Don't think so. The page loads, the user clicks the link and the js runs, the new element should be added. That's what I want. But when the link is clicked, the element is added and that's when turbolinks reloads the page...

Comment: Are you saying that the input gets appended to #watch-path-group before updating the page, instead of after updating the page?

Comment: @yezzz  - Yes exactly. I actually prefer that turbolinks didn't do anything at all. What I am trying to do is very simple; click the link, add the input to #watch-path-group. #watch-path-group is a list of paths that the user can extend by pressing the link.

Comment: Uhh... so you're saying the input should only be added after click on `<a href="#" id="add-item">`. That's what you didn't describe anywhere....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs, to disable turbolinks on certain links, you need to add  `data-turbolinks="false"` attribute to the element or any of its ancestors.

So the following should work:

```
<a href="#" id="add-item" data-turbolinks="false">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</a>
```

This of course assumes your own click handler is set up properly, your id's are unique, etc.